# Gulp - build files with custom folders

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm creating a workflow to build custom e-mail templates. In my folder, I have this structure:

```html
folder/
    templates/
        template-001.html
        image-001.jpg
    images/
        image-default.jpg
    src/
        style.scss
```

I'm using `gulp-inline-css` to get the compile css file and insert all the styles inline in the file `template-001.html`. Then, the task gets all these files and put inside a `build` folder. Like this:

```html
folder/
    templates/
        template-001.html
        image-001.jpg
    images/
        image-default.jpg
    src/
        style.scss
    build/
        template-001.html
        image-default.jpg
        image-001.jpg
```

This is ok for an individual project. But I want to be able to build several templates and organize the files the proper way. I would like to have a folder structure like this:

```html
folder/
    templates/
        template-001/
            template-001.html
            image-001.jpg
    images/
        image-default.jpg
    src/
        style.scss
    build/
        template-001/
            template-001.html
            image-default.jpg
            image-001.jpg
```

In other words, I want to be able to get the folder of the `template-001.html` and reproduce it in the `build` folder. With my current setup, I don't know how to make it possible.

Here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
        sass = require( 'gulp-sass' ),
        autoprefixer = require( 'gulp-autoprefixer' ),
        minifycss = require( 'gulp-minify-css' ),
        imagemin = require( 'gulp-imagemin' ),
        rename = require( 'gulp-rename' ),
        concat = require( 'gulp-concat' ),
        plumber = require( 'gulp-plumber' ),
        notify = require( 'gulp-notify' ),
        inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css'),
        projectTitle = 'E-mail Templates';

// styles task
gulp.task( 'styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/*.scss' )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sass({ paths: ['src/'] }) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'File: <%= file.relative %> was compiled!'
        } ) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'src/' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Minified file: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )

        console.log( '<%= file %>' );
} );

// styles task
gulp.task( 'html-build', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'templates/**/*.html' )
        .pipe( inlineCss({
                applyStyleTags: false,
                applyLinkTags: true,
                removeStyleTags: false,
                removeLinkTags: true
        }) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('build/') )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Template File: <%= file.relative %> was created / updated!'
        } ) )
} );

// images task
gulp.task( 'images', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'images/**/*' )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 7, progressive: true, interlaced: true }) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'build/' ) )
        .pipe( notify( {
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Image: <%= file.relative %> was optimized!'
        } ) )
} );

// watch task
gulp.task( 'watch', [ 'styles' ], function() {

    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch( 'src/**/*.scss', [ 'styles', 'html-build' ] );

    // Watch .html files
    gulp.watch( 'templates/**/*.html', [ 'html-build' ] );

    // Watch image files
    gulp.watch('images/**/*', ['images'] );

});
```

Any tips or advices about hot to make it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to copy all files from the template folder which aren't HTML to the dest folder?

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    return gulp.src(['templates/**/*','!templates/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

This will take this:

```
folder/
  templates/
    template-001/
      template-001.html
      image-001.jpg
    template-002/
      template-002.html
      image-002.jpg
    template-003/
      template-003.html
      image-003.jpg
```

and create this:

```
folder/
  build/
    template-001/
      image-001.jpg
    template-002/
      image-002.jpg
    template-003/
      image-003.jpg
```

This should do the trick and work with your other tasks. When I interpreted your Gulpfile correctly, the HTML files should already be in place. Do you also need help in copying the files in `images`?

### Update

I reworked the `images` task. Please read the comments to know what's going on:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
gulp.task('images', function(done) {
    // get all the directories inside templates. this will return
    // an array of folders
    var templates = fs.readdirSync('templates').filter(function(el) {
        return fs.statSync('templates/' + el).isDirectory()
    });

    // we start our stream with all the files from images we want to have
    var stream = gulp.src( 'images/**/*' )
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 7, progressive: true, interlaced: true }));

    // now we add a destination dir for each one of our
    // templates
    templates.forEach(function(el) {
        stream.pipe(gulp.dest('templates/' + el));
    });

    // we add the rest of our pipes
    stream.pipe(notify({
        title: projectTitle,
        message: 'Image: <%= file.relative %> was optimized!'
    }));

    // returning the stream kicks it off
    return stream;
});
```

Comment: Hey, @ddprrt! Thanks for the tip! What I want to do is copy all the files inside the folder `templates\template-001`, create a folder `template-001` inside the `build folder`, and "paste" all the copied files inside this created folder. My main main question is how to get the folder name `template-001` inside the `templates` folder, and create a new one, with the same name (`template-001`), inside the `build` folder. This way, I could separate the templates by folders inside `build`. Any tips on how to get the folder name?

Comment: do you really need the folder's name? With the code above the folder is generated + the files are copied into it

Comment: Hey, @ddprrt! Sorry, I should tested before! It does work as I need for the images inside each folder. I needed the html files copied too, so I removed the `'!templates/**/*.html'` glob and it worked ok! As you said, I wanted to copy for every new folder in `build`, all the files inside `images` folder too. The only thing that I couldn't understand yet is how can I run the other tasks to optimize the images and compile the html with inline css, then get these files and copy to the `build` folder. Should I put the `copy` task as a dependency for each other task?

Comment: For HTML compilation and inline CSS: As far as I see, your `html-build` task already does this. Please re-add the glob  `'!templates/**/*.html'` to `copy` and try running `html-build` afterwards. It already should put all files into the respective folders (If you take a hard look, the src and dest globs are rather similar to copy. As for the image optim task, let me think.. this one's a lot harder :D

Comment: GREAT! It works! I put the `copy` task as a dependency for `html-build`, and placed your `images` task. Now all the tasks works as expected! Thank you very much for the patience to help me out! I placed my updated `gulpfile.js` in a gist, so everyone can check it and use if need something similar: https://gist.github.com/diegoliv/80e942a1870e72b32c3e